# How to make Scanner Properly Read Escape Characters?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm reading from a file that reads something like all on one line:

```
Hello World!\nI've been trying to get this to work for a while now.\nFrustrating.\n
```

And my Scanner reads that from the file and puts it in a String:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
String str = input.nextLine();
System.out.print(str);
```

Now, I want the output then to be:

```
Hello World!
I've been trying to get this work for a while now.
Frustrating.
```

But instead I'm getting the exact same thing as the input. That is, each \n is included in the output and everything is on one line instead of separate lines.

I thought that Scanner would be able to read the escape character properly but it's instead copying it onto the String like it's \\n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `\n` is written is the file you can't use `nextLine()` because there is not `\n` (end of line) but instead there is `\\n` (two characters).

Instead try with a delimiter :

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/alain/Bureau/ttt.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter("\\\\n");
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```

Output :

> Hello World!
>
> I've been trying to get this to work for a while now.
>
> Frustrating.

EDIT:

If you want to read the file and replace the `\n` in the text with actual EOL. You can simply use :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/alain/Bureau/ttt.txt"));

//loop over real EOL
while(sc.hasNextLine()){

     //Replace the `\n` in the line with real EOL.
     System.out.println(sc.nextLine().replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `Scanner` won't do that for you. You'll have to do the translation yourself.

(Note that if you use something like `sc.useDelimiter("\\\\n")` as others have suggested you're breaking the functionality of the ordinary `next()` method and `nextLine()` may not function as expected.)

Here's a sketch of how I would solve it:

Change

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
```

to

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new JavaEscapeReader(new FileReader(fileName)));
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^
```

where `JavaEscapeReader` would extend [`FilterReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) like this:

```
class JavaEscapeReader extends FilterReader {

    JavaEscapeReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int ch = super.read();
        switch (ch) {
        case '\\':
            switch (super.read()) {
            case '\\': return '\\';
            case 'n': return '\n';
            case 't': return '\t';
            case 'f': return '\f';
            // ...
            default:
                throw new IOException("Invalid char sequence.");
            }
        default:
            return ch;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int i = 0, ch;
        while (i < len && -1 != (ch = read()))
            cbuf[i++] = (char) ch;
        return i == 0 ? -1 : i;
    }
}
```

Given an input file with the content

```
Line1\nLine2
Line3\nLine3
```

the program

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new JavaEscapeReader(new FileReader("filename.txt")));
while (sc.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

prints

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

---

Another option is to use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) and post process the read strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Scanner.useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) to set your own delimiter. In your case using double quoted `\\n`:

```
s.useDelimiter("\\\\n");
```

Example:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("Hello World!\\nI've been trying to get this to " +
                        "work for a while now.\\nFrustrating.\\n");
s.useDelimiter("\\\\n");

System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
System.out.println(s.next());
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World!
I've been trying to get this to work for a while now.
Frustrating.
```

Comment: Let's say that I need the input stored in a String for easy use in the future. 
Is there any way I can properly store the escape characters with just going straight to System.out?