# Scanner reading "\n" or Enter/Return key

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So, I'm trying to set up a simple config for a project. The goal here is to read certain values from a file and, if the file does not exist, to write said file. Currently, the creation of the file works fine, but my Scanner is acting a bit funny. When I reach the code

case "resolution": resolution = readConfig.next();

it makes the value of resolution "1024x768\nvsync" whereas it should only be "1024x768". If it were working as I planned, then the next value for

readingConfig = readConfig.next();

at the beginning of my while loop would be "vsync", which my switch statement would then catch and continue editing the values to those of the file.

Why is my Scanner picking up on the "\n" that is the 'enter' to the next line in the text document?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int musicVol = 0;
    int soundVol = 0;
    String resolution = null;
    boolean vsync = false;
    Scanner readConfig;
    String readingConfig;
    File configFile = new File(gameDir + "\\config.txt");
    if (configFile.exists() != true) {
        try {
            configFile.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(gameDir + "\\config.txt");
            writer.write("resolution = 1024x768 \n vsync = true \n music = 100 \n sound = 100");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        readConfig = new Scanner(configFile);
        readConfig.useDelimiter(" = ");
        while (readConfig.hasNext()) {
            readingConfig = readConfig.next();
            switch (readingConfig) {
            case "resolution":
                resolution = readConfig.next();
                break;
            case "vsync":
                vsync = readConfig.nextBoolean();
                break;
            case "music":
                musicVol = readConfig.nextInt();
                break;
            case "sound":
                soundVol = readConfig.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
        readConfig.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830366/how-to-make-scanner-properly-read-escape-characters

Comment: Do you want to read a file line by line? I have a handy method for that if that's your goal

Comment: @MCMastery I want to make a config file that can be edited both in the application and out of it with ease. Thus, the file looks something like "resolution = 1024x768 (skip line) vsync = false (skip line) music = 100 (skip line) sound = 100". I already have a way of reading a file line-by-line without the extra text, I used it for reading other files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `next()` which will not delimit your lines, try using `nextLine()` instead:

> String    **nextLine**() Advances this scanner past the current line and
>   returns the input that was skipped.

I'd suggest not using the delimiter, and get the whole line instead as a string,  and then split the string to the parts you want.

Something like

```
String nextLine = readConfig.nextLine();
String[] split = nextLine.split(" = ");
String resolution = split[1]; // just an example
...
```

Comment: If the delimeter weren't being used then resolution would be set to " = 1024x768\nvsync" -- you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .hasNext and .next(), you will have to use .hasNextLine() and .nextLine(). I would write this as a comment, but do not have enought rep to comment yet.

Comment: If the delimeter weren't being used then resolution would be set to " = 1024x768\nvsync" -- you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, solved!

What this does is pull the entire text file into a String (using Scanner.nextLine() removes the '\n') and then adds the " = " at the end of each line instead. Thus, when the Scanner runs back over the String for the switch, it will already be ignoring the " = " and pull the desired information from the String.

```
    String config = "";
    try {
        readConfig = new Scanner(configFile);
        while (readConfig.hasNext()) {
            config += readConfig.nextLine() + " = ";
            readConfig = new Scanner(config);
        readConfig.useDelimiter(" = ");
```